# How to access change widget property on another screen via python

Tags: python-3.x, widget, kivy

I have an App with 3 screens. On of them I have dissabled button which I want to unable according some conditions in IF statement in my py file.

Here is my main.kv

```
#:import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition

ScreenManagement:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    MainScreen:
    ProjectScreen:
    ScopeScreen:

<MainScreen>:
    name: 'main'
    scope_button : scope_bttn
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        spacing:10
        padding:10

#some wigedt..

        Button:
            on_press: app.root.current = 'project'
            text: 'Project Specification'
        Button:
            on_press: app.root.current = 'scope'
            text: 'Project Scope'
            disabled: True
            id: scope_bttn


<ProjectScreen>:
    name: 'project'      

        Button:
            on_release: app.root.current = 'main'
            text: 'Back'

        Button:
            text: 'Process'
            on_press: root.create_project()
            on_release: app.root.current = 'main'

<ScopeScreen>:
    name: 'scope'
#some widgets
```

Here is relevant part of my main.py

```
class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ProjectScreen(Screen):
    def create_project(self):
        If something True:
          here I would like to change property of scope_bttn.disable to true

class ScopeScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

presentation = Builder.load_file("main.kv")

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return presentation

ConfiguratorApp = MainApp()
ConfiguratorApp.run()
```

I know I should use ids but I couldn't find proper tutorial how to do it. I'm newbie to kivy and python.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use Kivy *ObjectProperty* to hook up to the id defined in kv file. Please refer to the example below for details.

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    main_scrn = ObjectProperty(None)


class MainScreen(Screen):
    scope_button = ObjectProperty(None)


class ProjectScreen(Screen):

    def create_project(self, root_manager):
        print("scope_button.disabled={}".format(root_manager.main_scrn.scope_button.disabled))
        if root_manager.main_scrn.scope_button.disabled:
            root_manager.main_scrn.scope_button.disabled = False
            print("scope_button.disabled={}".format(root_manager.main_scrn.scope_button.disabled))


class ScopeScreen(Screen):
    pass


class ConfiguratorApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ScreenManagement()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ConfiguratorApp().run()
```

### configurator.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0
#:import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition

<ScreenManagement>:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    main_scrn: main_screen
    MainScreen:
        id: main_screen
    ProjectScreen:
    ScopeScreen:

<MainScreen>:
    name: 'main'
    scope_button : scope_bttn
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        spacing:10
        padding:10

#some wigedt..

        Button:
            text: 'Project Specification'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'project'
        Button:
            text: 'Project Scope'
            disabled: True
            id: scope_bttn
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'scope'


<ProjectScreen>:
    name: 'project'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        spacing:10
        padding:10

        Button:
            on_release: root.manager.current = 'main'
            text: 'Back'

        Button:
            text: 'Process'
            on_press: root.create_project(root.manager)
            on_release: root.manager.current = 'main'

<ScopeScreen>:
    name: 'scope'
    #some widgets
```

### Output

[image]